# Spring bootのクラスが呼ばれた際の初期動作メソッド定義方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring bootのクラスが呼ばれた際の初期動作メソッド定義方法を教えてほしいのですが、
@Controllerクラスでは、通常のコンストラクタやinit()は機能せず、代わりに@PostConstractorや@autowiredなどがありますが、これらはクラスが呼ばれた際ではなくアプリ起動時に実行されるので、求めている動作と異なります。

クラスが呼ばれた際の初期動作メソッド定義方法が分かる方がいましたら、ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring AOPの@Beforeを用いることで実現することが出来ます。

[pom.xml]

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[Test.java]

```
@Aspect@Component
public class TestClass {

    @Before("当メソッド実行条件")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {
      ～
    }
}
```

[※当メソッド実行条件例](http://qiita.com/ARS_2000/items/386af61b6866d60964e8)